Mapping Functions EF Core to SQL
I'm looking for a more efficient way to grab my objects from the database and map them DTOs while using reusable methods.
Here are my database classes:
public class Sign
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public int? SignGroupId { get; set; }
    public SignGroup SignGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; } = null!;

    public static Expression<Func<Sign, SignDTO>> MapToDto()
    {
        return s => new()
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Name = s.Name ?? "",

            // this call works as I would expect by translating 
            // into SQL and executing it at the database level.
            Signs = s.SignGroup
                     .Signs
                     .Where(ss => ss.Id != s.Id)
                     .AsQueryable()
                     .Select(MapToGroupSignDto()).ToList(),

            // This call will end up bringing the whole Location 
            // object into memory and then perform the mapping from memory.
            LocationInfo = Location.MapToSignLocationDto()
                .Compile().Invoke(s.Location),
        };
    }

    public static Expression<Func<Sign, GroupSignDTO>> MapToGroupSignDto()
    {
        return gs => new()
        {
            Id = gs.Id,
            Name = gs.Name ?? "",
        };
    }
}

public class SignGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Sing> Signs { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Latitude { get; set; }
    public string? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string? State { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? Zip { get; set; }
    public string? StreetAddress { get; set; }
    
    public static Expression<Func<Location, SignLocationDTO>> MapToSignLocationDto()
    {
        return l => new()
        {
            Id = l.Id,
            Name = l.Name,
            Latitude = l.Latitude ?? "",
            Longitude = l.Longitude ?? "",
        };
    }
}

Here are my DTO classes:
public record SignDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public int SignGroupId { get; set; }
    [Comment("Signs At Same Location")]
    public List<GroupSignDTO> AdditionalSings { get; set; } = null!;

    public SignLocationDTO LocationInfo { get; set; } = null!;
}

public record GroupSignDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}

public record LocationDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Latitude { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Longitude { get; set; } = null!;
}

Here are my series of functions calls as they exist now. I know the expression functions are repeated in their above classes, but I wanted to make it easier to follow.
public async Task<List<SignDTO>> GetListDataAsync()
{
    IQueryable<Sign> signIQ = _context.Signs;
    Queryable<SignDTO> dtoIQ = signIQ.Select(Sign.MapToDto());

    return await dtoIQ.ToListAsync();
}

public static Expression<Func<Sign, SignDTO>> MapToDto()
{
    return s => new()
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Name = s.Name ?? "",

        // This call works as I would expect by translating 
        // into SQL and executing it at the database level.
        Signs = s.SignGroup
                 .Signs
                 .Where(ss => ss.Id != s.Id)
                 .AsQueryable()
                 .Select(MapToGroupSignDto()).ToList(),

        // This call will end up bringing the whole Location 
        // object into memory and then perform the mapping from memory.
        LocationInfo = Location.MapToSignLocationDto()
            .Compile().Invoke(s.Location),
    };
}

public static Expression<Func<Sign, GroupSignDTO>> MapToGroupSignDto()
{
    return gs => new()
    {
        Id = gs.Id,
        Name = gs.Name ?? "",
    };
}

public static Expression<Func<Location, SignLocationDTO>> MapToSignLocationDto()
{
    return l => new()
    {
        Id = l.Id,
        Name = l.Name,
        Latitude = l.Latitude ?? "",
        Longitude = l.Longitude ?? "",
    };
}

What I'm hoping to find, if possible, is a simple but also better way to grab the LocationInfo that would put the whole call into SQL and allow the database to only return what I really need without causing the SQL to take for ever to execute.
I don't like the idea of the database returning all the info related to the Location and then the server using memory to pair it down to what I really need.
I have tried various different ways to do this, but the only way that has accomplished what I wanted was to put all the code into a single Expression function like:
public static Expression<Func<Sign, SignDTO>> MapToDto()
{
    return s => new()
    {
        Id = s.Id,
        Name = s.Name ?? "",

        Signs = s.SignGroup.Signs.Where(ss => ss.Id != s.Id)
            .Select(gs => new()
            {
                Id = gs.Id,
                Name = gs.Name ?? "",
            ).ToList(),

        LocationInfo = new()
        {
            Id = s.Location.Id,
            Name = s.Location.Name,
            Latitude = s.Location.Latitude ?? "",
            Longitude = s.Location.Longitude ?? "",
        },
    };
}

My issue with this is that the code is not reusable in other areas and in order to maintain any future changes I'd have to go to multiple places.
Any help and ideas in this area would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you :)

LINQKit is usually the best way to handle this kind of problem: it lets you use syntax to invoke the expression directly (you'd probably call MapToSignLocationDto outside of your lambda, and use the result of the call inside it), and then "Expand" the query to replace such invocations with clones of their expressions. NeinLinq is an alternative. You can do the same thing yourself by creating an ExpressionVisitor that rewrites segments of an expression tree: it's just a little tricky.

would be able to show me how to use LINQKit to accomplish this?

Check this one

Svyatoslav Danyliv, Thank you for the link. This does appear to solve my issue at hand nicely. My only note on it is that in my specific use, it appears to add 65% more lines of Select fields to my sql when compared to adding the same code directly into the first expression select statement. Almost like it is grabbing all the fields from the all the other objects twice.  Though the execution time on my live database is the same.
